# Find the desired angle

Tags: trigonometry

I have a wall mounted camera looking at barcodes on warehouse shelves where all the shelves are a known size.

In order to calibrate the camera, I have some oversized QR codes that are mounted in specific locations (top-left of shelf, top right, bottom-left and bottom right).

The camera can successfully detect the QR codes and log their locations in pan/tilt coordinates: pan ($-180$ through $180$) and tilt ($-180$ though $180$).

I need to be able to tell the camera to pan to the leftmost portion of a specific shelf (say the 3rd shelf down) and start panning rightwards looking for content. Let's leave the 3-dimensional component out of it for now and focus on the top/bottom component.

Assuming that the whole shelf is 100" tall and the QR codes are 3" tall each. Assume further that I know the pan angle to the top and bottom of each QR code: topLeftQR-Top (black), topLeftQR-Bottom (green), BottomLeftQR-top (purple) and BottomLeftQR-Bottom (blue).

How do I find the correct pan angle (red) to target the camera to a specific desired location on the shelf (e.g. 45" up from the bottom).

[image]

Comment: The answer depends on a lot more - because perspective: Obviously, in your image with the camera very close to the top end, the angle to tilt down from top to middle is much larger that the angle from middle to bottom, whereas if the camera were exactly at middleheight, these two angles would be equal (by symmetry); and if the camera were near the bottom, the roles and sizes would be reversed. -- Simplest thing to do for real world applications: If the camera and the shelf do not move, simply log the positions for all shelf rows once and for all ...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExhange. You may find this tour helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour. The MathJax guide is quite usefull, too: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hagen, I was hoping that, with the knowledge of the values for the angles between black&green and the purple&blue coupled with the knowledge that they are equidistant in real life (the QR code is 3") that there was a trigonometric way to determine the angle for another known distance.

I persist in that hope

Comment: Sadly, the shelves DO move. They are on wheels. They are meant to be returned to the same general area where they live, but it is never perfect (hence the oversized QR codes to give us baseline location info)

Comment: Can we assume that the giant QR codes are coplanar, or nearly so?

Comment: Yes, they exist on the same plane

Comment: BTW, include a username prefixed with `@` in replies to comments if you want people to be notified of your response.

Comment: Since visual angles are the same for an object and its perspective projection, I think it would be sufficient to compute a homography between the image and plane of the shelf rack face, and then calibrate the focal length. You can then map a point on the shelf face to this image plane and use spherical coordinates to get the required camera direction. When I get some time I’ll write up a more detailed answer.

Comment: Hmm... don’t you want the *tilt* angle here? You’ve already got the correct pan from the left-side QR codes.

Comment: Having thought about it a bit, my previous suggestion is overkill for this problem. It solves the more general problem of finding the direction vector to specific points on a shelf face positioned arbitrarily relative to the camera. Here it looks like you’re only interested in a single edge of the shelves, and with the assumption that they’re nearly vertical, this is a straightforward triangulation problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Assume WLOG that your points are $(0,0) (3,0) (97,0), (100,0)$.  Assume your camera is at $(x,y)$.
2. Write down expressions for the distance from your camera to each above point, these will be algebraic functions of x and y.  (For example, the first is $sqrt(x^2+ y^2))$.  Call these distances $d_1,d_2,d_3, d_4$.
3. Write down the law of cosines for each of the 3 angles you have observed.
4. This should give you 3 equations in 2 unknowns, and you can backsolve for $(x,y)$.
5. Knowing $(x,y)$, use law of cosines again to find angle to arbitrary point $(t,0)$ that you are looking for.

I will note that this sounds very numerically sensitive - imagine in the limit that the QR codes were 1 millimeter wide, or that the camera was quite far off, this would easily fail due to rounding or measurement error.

Answer (score 0):

If the rack of shelves is near vertical and you don’t need a lot of precision to get the camera pointed at the correct shelf, then you can get a good result via simple triangulation.

[image]

Let positive tilt angles represent pointing the camera above the horizontal, and let $h$ be the known vertical distance between the upper and lower QR code target points and $d$ the horizontal distance from the camera to the shelf face. Referring to the above illustration, we have $$h={d\over\tan\alpha}+{d\over\tan\beta}$$ which when solved for $d$ gives $$d={\sin\alpha\sin\beta\over\sin(\alpha+\beta)}h.$$ Substituting $\alpha=\frac\pi2-\theta_{\text{top}}$ and $\beta=\frac\pi2+\theta_{\text{bot}}$ and simplifying, we end up with $$d={\cos\theta_{\text{top}}\cos\theta_{\text{bot}}\over\sin(\theta_{\text{top}}-\theta_{\text{bot}})}h.$$ A tilt angle of $0$ thus corresponds to a point at a distance of $d\tan\theta_{\text{top}}$ below the upper target (above if this value is negative, of course) and so the tilt angle for a point at a distance $y\ge0$ below the top satisfies $$\tan\theta={d\tan\theta_{\text{top}}-y\over d}=\tan\theta_{\text{top}}-\frac yd.$$ I’ll leave it to you to work out the corresponding formulas for distances measured from the bottom target instead. Watch out for sign errors!

If you need more precision than this or the shelves are not near-perpendicular to the camera’s zero-tilt line, then you’ll need to do something more elaborate, such as the calculation described in [Oren’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2331948/265466), or perhaps involving a homography between the camera image and the shelf-face plane (which isn’t particularly difficult to compute in this case). A potential benefit of the latter is that once you’ve computed the transformation matrix, you can find the world-coordinate ray from the camera to any point on the shelf-face plane.

One way to get a more accurate solution is to observe that the vertex of a triangle with a given angle and opposite side length lies on a circular arc. Let $\Delta\theta_{out}=\theta_{top}-\theta_{bot}$ be the angular difference between the tilt angles for the outer edges of the top and bottom QR codes, with actual distance $h$ between them, and let $\Delta\theta_{in}$ be the tilt angle difference between the inner edges, with distance $h-2q$. If we let the line segment from $(0,-h/2)$ to $(0,h/2)$ represent the shelf face, then the camera lies at the intersection of the circles $(x+c_{out})^2+y^2=r_{out}^2$ and $(x+c_{in})^2+y^2=r_{in}^2$. Subtracting the first equation from the second yields a linear equation for $x$ with solution $$x={(r_{out}^2-r_{in}^2)-(c_{out}^2-c_{in}^2)\over2(c_{out}-c_{in})}.\tag1$$ We also have $$r_{out}={h\over2\sin\Delta\theta_{out}}, c_{out}=r_{out}\cos\Delta\theta_{out} \\ r_{in}={h-2q\over2\sin\Delta\theta_{in}}, c_{in}=r_{in}\cos\Delta\theta_{in}.$$ Substituting these values into (1) and simplifying results in $$x={q(h-q)\over h\cot\Delta\theta_{out}-(h-2q)\cot\Delta\theta_{in}}.\tag2$$ The absolute value of $x$ is the perpendicular distance $d$ to the shelf face. From here, you can compute the $y$-coordinates of the intersections, choose the one that corresponds to the situation that you have, and use that point to compute a tilt angle bias $\delta$ (which is also the angle by which the shelves deviate from being perpendicular to the zero-tilt line). You can then proceed as before, adjusting the resulting tilt angles by $\delta$. This computation might also be necessary if the camera isn’t level, i.e., zero tilt is significantly off the horizontal.

Comment: One final note: Since you’re measuring along a linear feature, if you can identify three points along the edge of the shelves in a single camera view, you can then use cross-ratios to relate distances along this line in the world to distances along the image of the line. You still need to do something similar to the triangulation described above to turn that into a tilt angle, but the computation might be a bit simpler.